# AutoCompletTextView проверка части строки

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview

В своем приложении я использую `AutoCompleteTextView` для заполнения поля с электронной почтой. Необходимо как-то настроить `AutoCompleteTextView` для того чтобы он проверял строку после знака `@`, отбрасывая текст до знака.

Собственно, вопрос: как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
String mail = "";
if (txt.getText().toString().contains("@")) {
     String[] adressAndMail = txt.getText().toString().split("@");
     String adress = adressAndMail[0];
     mail = adressAndMail[1];
}

switch (mail){
     case "mail.ru":
     ...
}
```

Текст дробится на две части: до `@` и после, и добавляется в массив, откуда с ним уже можно работать.

`if` добавлен, чтобы избежать возможной ошибки.